# How to set the blog post's slug in Windows Live Writer 2011?

Tags: windows, windows-live-writer

I am trying to set my own slug text for a blog post in Windows Live Writer 2011 and I am unable to find how to do it.

Comment: also I am using blogspot.com

Answer (score 6):

On the bar where you can set the categories and tags there is a "View all" button, click 
that and in the list that opens up you will see an option for "slug" which you can edit.

[image]

Comment: i am unable to see this option what should i do ?

Comment: also I am using blogspot.com

Comment: I can't see any reason why you wouldn't have that toolbar.  Does anything happen if you press F6 while editing the post?  F6 *should move to the post properties field...

Comment: F6 didnt do the magic, any other suggestions?

Comment: The only other thing I can think to do is to check you have the latest version, If you click the file menu (blue button in the top right corner) then select "About Windows Live Writer"  my version has literally just updated to "Version 2011 (15.4.3538.513)"

Comment: mine is also same version ..

Comment: Is there away to automatically fill in the slug?